# The method or operation is not implemented in collection using LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, collections

I am getting the exception when I try to loop into a collection.

//Code

```
fieldFormatDropDown.DataSource = From FieldFormatLinq In fieldFormatsCollection Where FieldFormatLinq.DataTypeId = dataTypeId And FieldFormatLinq.IsActive = True
```

//Exception:

```
The method or operation is not implemented
```

Why i'm getting this?

Comment: What is the type of `fieldFormatsCollection`? And please post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: the same question is asked [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/843638c5-277b-40bd-b016-89050e2b7c61/unhandled-exception-the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented-), try converting the `IEnumerable` to a `List` before assigning it to `DataSource`.

Comment: You should almost always use `AndAlso` instead of `And` and `OrElse` instead of `Or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting into `Tolist()`.

//Code

```
fieldFormatDropDown.DataSource = (From FieldFormatLinq In fieldFormatsCollection Where FieldFormatLinq.DataTypeId = dataTypeId And FieldFormatLinq.IsActive = True).ToList()
```

Comment: That should solve the problem since a DataSource must implement IListSource. However, i prefer two lines in VB.NET: `Dim query = From ....` and `fieldFormatDropDown.DataSource = query.ToList()`